# Inner print statement not working

Tags: debugging, python-2.7, printing

I'm learning algorithms. I implemented insertion sort today. I have no idea why the inner print statement doesn't work here. The algorithm works correctly though.

```
def insertionSort(array):
    if len(array) > 1:
        for j in range(1, len(array) ):
            print "outer j is: "+ str(j) 
            while j > 0 and array[j-1] > array[j]:
                array[j-1], array[j] = array[j], array[j-1]
                j = j - 1
                print "inner j is: "+ str(j) 
        return array 
    else:
        return array
```

Both of the print statements work in this snippet:

```
def forWhile():
    for i in range(1,10):
        print "outer loop i is:" + str(i)
        while i > 0:
            i = i - 1
            print "inner loop i is " + stri(i)
```

I slept for 8 hours and then came back and now the inner loop works.

I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me.

```
>>> insertionSort([3,4,5,6,1,2])
outer j is: 1
outer j is: 2
outer j is: 3
outer j is: 4
inner j is: 3
inner j is: 2
inner j is: 1
inner j is: 0
outer j is: 5
inner j is: 4
inner j is: 3
inner j is: 2
inner j is: 1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Maybe you're using an ordered array as your input, so there is no need to enter inner loop.

```
>>> insertionSort([1,2,3,4])
outer j is: 1
outer j is: 2
outer j is: 3
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: OP here.

I slept for 8 hours and then came back and now it works.